# iOS Archive "Upload to App Store" buttons grayed out

Tags: ios, xcode

[image: Buttons grayed out.]

I have an active subscription to iTunes Connect.

Most of the resources on this topic are outdated, and apple tech support is on vacation for the next week (yes really). Has anyone seen this before?

I should note that this archive is indeed an iOS App Archive.

Comment: Did you have the active account in you mac?

Comment: What do you mean in my mac? When I click XCode > preferences > accounts I see it there. Im not sure exactly what you mean you might be onto something!

Comment: i mean the same as you done. i felt this before and i was not add apple account on there. Did you add the ad hoc provisional profile to your project?

Comment: provisional file is there

Comment: cool friend. how many times u tried and got this again?

Comment: It says "Distribution requires enrollment in the **Apple Developer Program**" in the screenshot.

Comment: I know. I am enrolled though. When I click that link it brings me to my logged in Apple Developer account.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is due to the same reason you mentioned yourself. Apple's App Store went on vacation for a week and throughout this time disabled the App Upload. The button and upload will work again tomorrow.

> As a reminder, we will not be accepting new app or app update submissions from December 22-29. If you plan to release apps during this time, they should be submitted, approved, and scheduled in advance. Other iTunes Connect and developer account functionality will remain available.

More info can be found [here](https://developer.apple.com/news/?id=12102015a).

Hope that helps, Julian

Comment: Thanks for catching this before I butchered my app with unecessary edits. Great observation thanks again!

Comment: No problem at all :-)

Answer (score 2):

I know this is late but for anyone else who comes across this problem, I had the wrong provisioning profile option in the build settings. I changed it to the right one, then Archived the App and bing the Upload to App Store was enabled.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes this issue exist when you have linked frameworks or static libraries which has `skip install` flag set to `NO` in the build settings. Make sure that all the static libraries or frameworks has `skip install` to `YES` and you app's `skip install` settings to `NO`.